# Unable to start memcache on windows

Tags: memcached

I tried to starte memcache on windows 32 bit using the below command from cmd:-

**D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.4.5-x86\memcached-x86>memcached.exe -d**

This is the error i am getting:-

**Failed to ignore SIGHUP: Result too large**

Has the command changed for starting 1.4.5 version?

I tried the below option also :-

**B) Installation of memcached >= 1.4.5:**

Extract the memcached windows binary to any directory.
In version 1.4.5 or later, memcached cannot run as a service. It must be started as a normal process using the task scheduler. To configure the memcached process to run automatically every time windows start, run a command prompt and type the following:

**schtasks /create /sc onstart /tn memcached /tr "'c:\memcached\memcached.exe' -m 512"**

Meanwhile, to remove the scheduled memcached task, run the following command:

**schtasks /delete /tn memcached**

But i am getting an **access denied error message** then. Do we need to give any special access rights for running memcahe.

Note:- I am totally new to memcache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command should be run as administrator. You have to right-click the command prompt and use the option to "Open as Administrator".

Answer (score 3):

According to the information on this page:

https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows

version 1.4.5 or later can not be installed as a service. It must be installed as a Windows task.
To create this tasks via command line (or batch file), do in a manner similar to the example below:

**CREATE TWO MEMCACHED TASKS**

```
SCHTASKS /create /sc onstart /ru system /tn memcached1 /tr "C:\Xampp\memcached\memcached.exe -m64 -p11211"
SCHTASKS /create /sc onstart /ru system /tn memcached2 /tr "C:\Xampp\memcached\memcached.exe -m256 -p11212"
```

The tasks above will run on restart. 
Note the different amount of memory and port number, on every instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to run the memcached on Windows:

1. Right click on the memcached.exe file and click on "Run as administrator", it will start the memcached.

   2. Press "Window"+R, then type "cmd" and then press "Ctrl+Shift+Enter". It run it as administrator. Ten go to the lication of the file and use "memcached.exe -start" to run the memcached.

Hope this will help someone.